# How to add an instantiated object to a Stage in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my GamePanel class that is connected to its super class startUp.java (the startUp class is not listed).

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.LIGHTGREEN;
import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED;

public class GamePanel extends Stage {
private boolean axisDown, axisUp, yawLeft, yawRight, throttleUp,    throttleDown;
private double xPosition = 0, yPosition = 0, zPosition = 0;
private int resolutionX = 0, resolutionY = 0;
private int speedValue = 0;
private int throttleValue = 10;//Make sure that throttle doesnt go below 10%.. will add stall feature that will allow you to go to 0% throttle in future version
private int altitudeValue = 5000; //crashes will occur when you touch an object such as a mountain or if altitudeValue is <= 0

//angle increment variables
private int yAngleIncrementInitializer = 180;
private int xAngleIncrementInitializer = (1100/2)-150;
private int incrementLength = 300;
private int incrementValue = 5;//CORRECT LATER

public GamePanel()
{
    super();
    startGame(this);
}

public void startGame(Stage GamePanel)
{
    angleIncrement[] angleIncrementsArray = new angleIncrement[71];
    for(int incrementNamePlace = 0; incrementNamePlace < 71; incrementNamePlace ++)
    {
        angleIncrementsArray[incrementNamePlace] = new angleIncrement(incrementLength, incrementValue, xAngleIncrementInitializer, yAngleIncrementInitializer);
        angleIncrementsArray[incrementNamePlace].displayIncrement();
        yAngleIncrementInitializer+=5;
    }
}
```

Now here is my angleIncrement class that is instantiated to make 72 lines.

```
    import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class angleIncrement
    {
public int length;
public int incrementValue;
public int xPlacement;
public int yPlacement;
public angleIncrement(int incrementLength, int incrementValue, int xAngleIncrementInitializer, int yAngleIncrementInitializer)
    {
    super();
    //displayIncrement(this);
    length = incrementLength;
    this.incrementValue = incrementValue;
    xPlacement = xAngleIncrementInitializer;
    yPlacement = yAngleIncrementInitializer;
    }
    public void displayIncrement()
    {
    Line newIncrement = new Line();
    newIncrement.setStartY(yPlacement);
    newIncrement.setEndX(newIncrement.getStartX()+300);
    newIncrement.setEndY(newIncrement.getStartY());
    }

}
```

So I want it to be able to print lines that are 5 pixels apart in terms of their y values. For this to work I believe the problem is that I cannot print these lines in my angleIncrement object because the object "Line" is a member of the javaFX library which I can't get in my angle increment object without making a whole new stage.

If someone could help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Try to provide a better narrative of your question, and keep code quotes to the relevant parts.

Comment: My question is, how do I make these angleIncrement objects that I declare appear in my GamePanel stage

Comment: What's the purpose of creating 71 windows and a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the `startGame` method?

Comment: Sorry the "extends Stage" wasn't supposed to be there. And my goal is to make 72 lines that are 5 pixels apart on the y-axis.